# Does iterator throw ConcurrentModificationException when an element of a collection is modified from a different thread?

Tags: java, concurrency

Lets say we have an `ArrayList` of some objects and we're iterating through the list to read each object's characteristics. Does iterator throw a `ConcurrentModificationException` if an object in the list is modified by another thread at any moment (before iterator reaches the object, while it's on the object and after it iterates through the object)?

While writing this I realized that the list actually holds references to the objects and they stay the same when the object is modified, so the iterator shouldn't throw `ConcurrentModificationException`, but the data that is read while iterating can be inconsistent, unless the actuall read process is synchronized. Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: *"Can anyone confirm this?"* Yes, you are correct.

Comment: Javadoc CME: "it is not generally permissible for one thread to **modify a Collection** while another thread is iterating over it." (the collection, not its elements); `ArrayList`: "if **the list is structurally modified** ..., the iterator will throw a ConcurrentModificationException" (structurally modified: adding/removing elements, thtat is, changing the size of the list, but does not include the elements being changed)